# php : reading json data in php using file _get_content

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am trying to read the json data from a php file .Here is my code .

category-query.php (Here is my json data )

```
<script>
var json_data = 
[
                /*
                !please notice
                you can add the category name SpecialFeature, 
                but it will be igone in the main menu
                */
                //cat 1
                {
                        "categoryName"      : "Dishes",  
                        "categoryImageUrl"  : "cat_01.jpg" ,
                        "categoryRootMenu"  : false ,
                        "categoryStyle" : "one"
                },
                //cat 2
                {
                        "categoryName"          : "Dessert",  
                        "categoryImageUrl"  : "cat_02.jpg" ,
                        "categoryRootMenu"  : false ,
                        "categoryStyle" : "two"

                },
                //cat 3
                {
                        "categoryName"          : "Dimsum",  
                        "categoryImageUrl"  : "cat_04.jpg" ,
                        "categoryRootMenu"  : false ,
                        "categoryStyle" : "submenu"

                }   ]
```

Here is what i am doing on index .php to read above values

```
    $get_category = file_get_contents("res3/resproj-data/category-query.php");
                        $decode = json_decode($get_category);
                        print $decode;
                        ?>
```

unfortunately i am not able to get these value in `$decode`  variable please  tell me how can i read those values

Answer (score 1):

The contents of your file are not JSON; they look like are HTML that includes JavaScript code through `<script>`.

In order for `json_decode` to process the data the two first lines would need to be removed:

```
<script>
var json_data =
```

It's entirely not clear why your file has a `.php` extension, or why it would need to include JavaScript code. If there are interactions between this data file and other parts of your app you should mention it in the question.

Comment: basically i am designing a system which wil read the data from some other server so my cleint told me to use just json fromat   is there any better way to do this just do let me knwo

Comment: @burning: Well, you are not using JSON format. `<script>` and `var json_data = ...` is not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a well formed JSON script, I think you want to have an associative array in php so use : `json_decode($datas,true);`.
Then to test if your array is well parsed, it is not "print" you want to use but `var_dump`.
And apart from displaying it, if you want to traverse it, use a foreach loop.

If you do not get a well formed JSON, as Jon thinks, review your script.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution allows you to use only php. JS is not required.

**Case 1:**
If you use a php file, you could just include it (it will be executed)
File: category-query.php

```
<?php
  $categories = array() ;

      //Push categories and cast them to objects
      $categories[] = (object) array(
        "categoryName"     => "Dimsum",  
        "categoryImageUrl" => "cat_04.jpg",
        "categoryRootMenu" => false,
        "categoryStyle"    => "submenu"
      ) ;   

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($categories) ; 
?>
```

**Case 2:**
If you dont need to execute the script and want use file_get_contents:

File: category-query.php

```
[{"categoryName":"Dimsum","categoryImageUrl":"cat_04.jpg","categoryRootMenu":false,"categoryStyle":"submenu"}]
```

File: index.php

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("category-query.php") ;
$categories = json_decode($data) ;

if (!is_null($categories)){
  Use your array with objects
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

See this example of my code

```
$Link = SITE.'service/Controller.php?request='.ABS.'&action='.SEARCH_CLIENT.'&data='.json_encode($data);  
$ResultArray = array();
  $Result = file_get_contents($Link);
  $jsonResponse = json_decode($Result,true);
  $ResultArray = $jsonResponse[JSON_DATA];
```

if you print_r the $jsonResponse variable you will have an associate array then you will get the values from assoicate array then. Beacuse json decode convert the json into an array.

Comment: example code only works if source file output contains only JSON, which is not the case with OP

Answer (score 0):

Apart from that it's extremely odd to fetch data from a file that is under your control with file_get_contents() you can only successfully decode JSON into a PHP array if the source is utf8. Try this:

```
$get_category = utf8_encode(file_get_contents("res3/resproj-data/category-query.php"));
$decode = json_decode($get_category, true);
print_r $decode;
```